# In QT, How to define the geometry for the Layout in a custom Widget

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qwidget

In a custom `QWidget` (say `MyWidget`) I include a layout to manage children widgets:

```
MyWidget window;
QPushButton button;
QVBoxLayout layout(window);
layout.addWidget(button);
window.show();
```

I would like the layout to be in a specific position and size, by default, QWidget set it to the whole geometry.

How can I set the geometry the `layout` will consider for managing his space?

As an indirect question:
Which function the layout use to set children geometries?

Answer (score 1):

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
verticalLayout->addSpacing(300);
verticalLayout->addWidget(button);
button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
button->setMinimumSize(500, 200);
button->setMaximumSize(500, 200);
```

If you need both vertical and horizontal spacing - use `QGridLayout`.

Comment: This is a good answer for a specific GUI, but not as a generic solution for the problem. The question is about how to define the inner geometry the layout use, from the custom widget perspective. It is also easy to override the "setGeometry" function of the layout to set the QRect; but again, that is not a generic solution.

Comment: If you need fixed window size and fixed widgets' positions - you just don't use layouts.

Comment: I do not need fixed size and position, but to implement MyWidget in a way it allow any layout and any GUI to be set inside.

Comment: Would `QGraphicsView` + `QGraphicsScene` + `QGraphicsWidget` solve your problem?

Comment: I am currently trying to override ´MyWidget::contentsMargins´, but it does not work as ´QWidget´ base function is not virtual. Writing a code to maintain the native margins and those of the layout seem a solution, but it is not elegant at all.

Comment: Why do you need to override `contentsMargins`, when you can set them?

Comment: I can set contentsMargins of my custom MyWidget in the constructor, but I cannot set the contentsMargins of the Layout in MyWidget constructor.

Comment: Ok, you are right, the layout make the sum of both: the container and the layout margins.

Answer (score 0):

The QLayout use as margins the summary of both:

- The parent widget contents margins.
- The layout contents margins.

The solution is to set the contents margins to the required value in the custom widget constructor. And when creating the layout, to set his contents margins to 0.

```
this->setContentsMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
// ...
layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

The Layout setGeometry is called by QWidget resize event, and set children widgets size according with it. As all functions are not virtual, it is not possible (or at least difficult) to modify in this behavior.